# ...much to the increase of.. What is the meaning of "to"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

The following quote is from "Manfield Park" by Jane Austen:

Everything was now in a regular train: theatre, actors, actresses, and dresses, were all
getting forward; but though no other great impediments arose, Fanny found, before many days
were past, that it was not all uninterrupted enjoyment to the party themselves, and that she had
not to witness the continuance of such unanimity and delight as had been almost too much for
her at first. Everybody began to have their vexation. Edmund had many. Entirely against his
judgment, a scene-painter arrived from town, and was at work, **much to the increase of** the
expenses, and, **what was worse**, **of the eclat of their proceedings**; and his brother, instead of
being really guided by him as to the privacy of the representation, was

My question: 1) Is "much to" used expressing a resulting state or condition? i.e.The increase of the expenses resulted from the arrival of a scene-painter from town?
2) Does "of the eclat of their proceedings" refer back to "the increase of"? i.e. ...what was worse, much to the increase of the eclat of their proceedings,
3) By "what was worse",  I understand it to mean "the increase of the eclat of their proceedings" was worse. I can't figure out why "the increase of the eclat of their proceedings was something worse.

Comment: Employing a professional scene-painter increased the expenses. Worse still (in Edmund's view) it helped to make the production a big event instead of the small private affair that had originally been planned.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I agree with your explanation, which is very convincing.

Answer (score 2):

"much to the X of Y" is an idiom.

*Much to the delight of the children the birthday cake appeared.*

*Much to the dismay of the diner, the waitress spilled soup on her dress.*

also

*Much to my astonishment a gorilla emerged from the trees.*

I'm not sure how to described it grammatically. Maybe the event adds *much* to my feelings.

---

> Entirely against his judgment, a scene-painter arrived from town, and was at work, much to the increase of the expense...

Paraphrase:

*Entirely against his judgment, a scene-painter arrived from town, and was at work, thus much increasing the expense ...*

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Your explanation is very helpful.